# PHP function getimagesize() gives "Read error" when trying to get https url

Tags: php, ssl, https, openssl, getimagesize

I am trying to use getimagesize with URL and with http everything is fine. However when trying to use function on https url I am getting "Read error" Notice and false as result. I checked and I have OpenSSL 0.98 installed on the server (so it should be working with https as well). 
I know that I can download the image first and then use it but it seems to me like this should work and that I am missing something. Could you please provide me with some solution (other than downloading the image first and then opening it) ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although it may be irrelevant for this (as there may be no check for that): Is the certificate of the domain you try to download from signed by an authority known to the system?

Comment: I was testing with FB image so yes...

Comment: In the end I went with downloading the image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents()` as an alternate solution..

```
<?php
$filename='something';
file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($url));
$size = getimagesize($filename);
var_dump($size);
```

Comment: "other than downloading the image first and then opening it" I was hoping for some server || php configuration to resolve the issue...

Comment: @Goran, _as an alternate solution.._ that's what the answer says.. Will find a way for your problem.

Comment: The main problem is that getimagesize is used in third party library. That means if I change anything in it, first time anyone updates it with composer it will roll back. That is why I need to see why am I getting this error and if I fail to find the answer I will adjust my way of coding (download first and then give file path). Thank you for the alt answer though!

Comment: @Goran, Can you post the exact notice / error on the question ?

Comment: Damnit , Weird part is that it works on my system. (_the actual problem_)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) only shifts the problem instead of solving it when you don't change any of SSL's settings. But you can achieve that thru [`stream_context_create`](https://www.php.net/stream_context_create) and then fiddling with the [SSL settings](https://www.php.net/context.ssl). Once you did that you're also able to pass what SSL wants to protect you from.

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL );
header( 'Content-type: text/plain' );

// The remote file to check
$sPic= 'https://picture.to/check/for/details.png';

// Does it work right away?
$aInfo= @getimagesize( $sPic );
if( $aInfo=== FALSE ) {
    // No. Then a temporary file needs to be created.
    if( $sTmp= tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'sig' ) ) {
        // Tweaking the HTTPS options to weaken/ignore security
        $hCtx= stream_context_create
        ( array
            ( 'ssl'=> array
                ( 'verify_peer'=> FALSE  // Certificate verification
                , 'verify_peer_name'=> FALSE
                , 'allow_self_signed'=> TRUE
                , 'SNI_enabled'=> TRUE  // Multiple certificates on same IP address
                )
            )
        );

        // Download file
        $sPayload= file_get_contents( $sPic, FALSE, $hCtx );
        if( $sPayload!== false ) {
            // Success: write to temporary file
            if( file_put_contents( $sTmp, $sPayload ) ) {
                $aInfo= @getimagesize( $sTmp );
            } else die( 'Could not write to tempfile!' );
        } else die( 'Could not download file!' );

        // Delete temporary file
        unlink( $sTmp );
    } else die( 'Could not get tempfile name!' );
}

// Picture file details
print_r( $aInfo );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updating OpenSSL may solve your problem.**

Judging from the OpenSSL version you report you have on server this problem may be caused by the server having a newer version of SSL than your client.

The Facebook server is probably using a version >= 1.0.0 or a custom SSL library, while you are using an old 0.9.8.

**Heartbeat overflow issue forced many webservers to update their OpenSSL version.**

A random article about OpenSSL 1.0.0 handshake issues with clients using 0.9.8 version:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/jSOTOQXPnwU

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We will upload OpenSSL extension and let you know ASAP.

Comment: @Goran Haha, "ASAP".